# Replace one letter with other letter in dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to replace a letter in the string by value in dictionary one digit at the time and add to a list:

```
dictionary = {'a':'oe', 'b':'it'}
string = 'ab'
# return list should be
list = ['ob','eb','ai', 'at']

def replace(string):
       """ 
       Return a list of all possible string
       """
       list = []
       for idx in string:
           if idx is key:
               # do somethin to replace dict[key] with dict[value]
               list.append(string)
               return list
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want this should do it:

```
from string import maketrans

dictionary = {'a':'oe', 'b':'it'}
string = 'ab'

def replace(target):
   """ 
   Return a list of all possible string
   """
   result = []
   for k,values in dictionary.iteritems():
     for c in values: 
        trans = maketrans(k, c)
        result.append( target.translate(trans) )

  return result
```

Comment: what is maketrans does? When I ran it it said not defined

Comment: it was missing an import. fixed.